# How do you make the Chrome Developer Tools only show your console.log?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

It adds logs when plugins say something. It adds logs when it gets anything from the cache manifest. It logs HTTP information sometimes.

My 1 little log gets flooded by 10,000 logs I don't need or want.

Answer (score 1):

Use only in development:

```
(function(){
    var originalConsole = window.console;

    window.console = {};
    window.console.log = window.console.debug = window.console.error = function(){};

    window.myLog = function() {
        originalConsole.log.apply(originalConsole, arguments);
    };
}());
```

This will save a local copy of the original `window.console` object.

It will change the original `window.console` object to use empty functions.

And finally it will define a global `myLog` function which will use the local copy of the original `window.console` to actually log stuff.

This way all the other code will use the useless `console.log()` and your code could use `myLog()`.

Answer (score 1):

on the Console tab select No info on the left Hand [I have attached a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5zvT.png)
You should update to the google chrome latest version

Comment: You're a legend. This works perfectly in Chrome 84.